# URLSession dataTask - error checking - Cannot assign through '!': 'err' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to check the error object in the callback delegate that runs for my dataTask. However, I get a compile error on the if statement:

> Cannot assign through '!': 'err' is a 'let' constant

Apple documentation specifies err (error) will be nil if there are no errors.  So, the first thing I want to do is check if err is nil.  Reasonable to me.  But, it's not working.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err ) in
    if err!=nil
    {
        //There was an error  
    }
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace matters. The line:

```
if err!=nil
```

is being parsed as:

```
if err! = nil
```

which is trying to assign `nil` to the forced-unwrapped value `err` and `err` is a constant so you can't assign to it.

Write the line as:

```
if err != nil
```

Better yet:

```
if let err = err {
    print("Error: \(err)")
}
```